# behavioral difference between std::unique_lock<std::recursive_mutex> in C++17 and pthread_mutex_lock with PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE

Tags: c++, linux, g++, pthreads, c++17

This is about [issue#16](https://gitlab.com/bstarynk/refpersys/issues/16) on gitlab of the GPLv3+ project [RefPerSys](https://refpersys.org/)  (commit [`9eeefe585b5`](https://gitlab.com/bstarynk/refpersys/commit/9eeefe585b5f21cdf917329368e56024cbb237a0)) coded in C++17 on Linux/Debian/Unstable using [GCC 9](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-9/) (package `g++ 9.2.1-1` on Debian/Sid/x86-64) and [Qt](https://qt.io/) 5.12 (package `qtbase5-dev` v 5.12.5+dfsg-5 on january 2020) and [libjsoncpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp) (package `libjsoncpp-dev` 1.7.4-3). Linux kernel is Debian 5.4.0, the GNU glibc is package `libc-bin` 2.29-7

I thought that [semantically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)), if we have some `std::recursive_mutex mtx;` a local declaration `std::unique_lock<std::recursive_mutex> gu(mtx);`  is behaving *exactly* like [`pthread_mutex_lock`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_lock) with `PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE`.

With `gdb` 8.3.1, it looks like it is not the case. the code is blocking on [line 963 of file `object_rps.cc`](https://gitlab.com/bstarynk/refpersys/blob/master/objects_rps.cc#L963), and I really don't understand why.

Hence my question:

#### what is the behavioral difference between `std::unique_lock<std::recursive_mutex> gu(mtx);` in C++17 and `pthread_mutex_lock` with pthreads in C99 (or C11) using flag `PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE` ?

Up to now (2020, jan 4 at 10:09 PM UTC), I thought that the C++17 lock was calling such a `pthread_mutex_lock`.... But I am obviously wrong.

What am I misunderstanding? How to debug such bugs?

Comment: Now, I only had a quick look at the code to see what it is roughly doing, but it seems to me that your function `make_new_symbol` from yesterdays commit is missing a return statement [here](https://gitlab.com/bstarynk/refpersys/blame/master/objects_rps.cc#L1008). Although I would be very surprised if the compiler hadn't flagged that for you.

Comment: @walnut: thank you so much. I am confused. Happy new year.

Comment: So did that solve the issue? (I would assume so since the mutex would be practically uninitialized when you try to lock it.) I don't think `std::recursive_mutex` and the pthread equivalent are supposed to behave differently in any way.  (Throwing exceptions on failure aside.) From what I can tell looking at the libstdc++ source `std::recursive_mutex` just calls the identical pthreads functions. Is that worth an answer?

Comment: @walnut: the issue is partly solved (no more `core` dump, but still buggy). That is definitely an answer, and it would be even better if you could find a phrasing in some C++ standard about it.